# Replacing a newline with a <br> - PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm guessing this is something you can do in PHP. What I want is to get the text in a textfield when the submit button is pressed and convert all the newlines into

```
<br>'s.
```

Help, please?

Comment: exactly related to question quick advice: **increase your google search skill**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) would do what you want, I think.

```
<?php
$str = "\n\nfoo\nbar";
echo nl2br($str);
```

Output:

```
<br />
<br />
foo<br />
```

Comment: But then wouldn't people need to type in \n to get new lines?

Comment: @user921489 No: `\n` is [a way of saying "new line" in code](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates it better:

```
$str = "This is a
multiline
string";
echo nl2br($str);
```