# Converting \n to <br />

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing a newline with a <br> - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370635/replacing-a-newline-with-a-br-php)

```
file_put_contents('./files/'.$count.'.txt',$input);
```

How do you append a `<br/>` tag per line of the file because \n isn't recognized in HTML. 
for Example, the content of the file was:

```
A
B
C
D
```

the output in html is just

`ABCD`

Or should there be a better way, like replacing `\n` with `<br/>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert all line breaks to `<br />`.

Comment: No problem. You might want to consider changing the title of your question a little so it better reflects question and answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/function.nl2br.php) before saving the contents. It will replace all `"\n"` with `<br />`:

```
file_put_contents('./files/'.$count.'.txt',nl2br($input));
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people have suggested, if adding `<br />` tags is all you need, simply pass the string through `nl2br()`.

In case you wanted to add another string to end of each line, or maybe preserve the newline characters while adding the `<br />` you could do something like this:

```
$appendStr = "arbitrary string you wish to append";
$rows = explode("\n", $str);
$contents = implode ( $appendStr . "\n", $rows );
```