# Replace '\n' with '<br>' PHP SQL table

Tags: php, sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing a newline with a <br> - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370635/replacing-a-newline-with-a-br-php)

I am presenting a table with information from my SQL database. When I insert into MySQL database I add:

```
\n
```

When I 'draw' the database I can just replace it with:

```
<br>
```

and it should add a new line. Here's what I tried and it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't replace the `\n` with `<br>` and I don't see what I did wrong.(Here is the code thats in the following picture if you'd like to test this yourself; http://pastebin.com/PgWKD5Mg)

[image: Image of me replacing the string]

But that doesn't seem to work. It doesn't replace the strings, but if i replace `$row['Info']` with something like `Hello \n Test` it *does* print `hello` and `Test` onto seperate lines, that code renders this:

[image]

Note: **nl2br function also does not work, and this does the same as that regardless**

Comment: Don't use MYSQL_**. try PDO, and if I want to test your code I like copy/paste. Avoid giving us nice pictures

Comment: If neither `str_replace` nor `nl2br` are working, then the values may not actually have newline characters in them. When viewing the resulting markup, does it include `\n` literally?

Comment: Yes, i posted a picture of the database with the edits i made.
It does actually have the character '\n' but it simply wont change it.

Comment: @Cacoon The issue is likely that those are sets of "\" and "n" characters rather than the escape sequence, "\n". Newlines should render in a browser as a space. Try derWilly's answer.

Comment: @cryptic its a different problem, i already looked round those sorts of threads to sort my problem out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `str_replace("\\n", "<br>", $row['Info']);`

Comment: +1 And next time insert real newlines into your database. Not "backslash" + "n".

Comment: Worked great.
Thanks mate.

Comment: ... or simply use `'\n'` instead of `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
echo nl2br($result);
```

Comment: Does not work sadly ):
Thanks though.